# Does double-down vote remove a potential audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, downvotes

I recently learned to undo an upvote or downvote requires another upvote or downvote. Doh...

If I want to remove a potential audit question from the pool, will a double downvote accomplish it? I'm a conservative down voter, and the double downvote will leave the score unchanged, which is the behavior I want for many questions I encounter that have minor issues.

But I'm not sure if the double downvote removes the question from the pool of potential audits.

Comment: for close review audits, any _single_ vote in an "opposite" direction drops the known good audit as [explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773). OTOH, First Post audits are known to survive [single vote down and close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773 "see 'Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?'")

Comment: Thanks gnat. I was not sure if the double vote negated audit eligibility too, and Shog made it clear.

Comment: I started editing but realized I was changing the post too much.  Your "double downvoting" concept is only going to be confusing because it is a made up term.  I would advise you to rewrite this to remove that term and just describe it for what it is "voting then immediately removing the vote".

Comment: What's a double downvote?

Comment: @Robert: that's what's required to retract a down vote - you have to down vote twice (instead of doing something obvious like using an up vote to cancel a down vote).

Comment: Erm.  Well, it's a toggle switch, is it not?  The tooltip even explains how it works.

Comment: @Robert - Perhaps that's the problem. The voting system uses an Up/Down control, and not a Toggle control. Pigeon holing toggle behavior into up/down is not intuitive. I recently learned about it because I finally went searching and found a discussion on Meta (so others have had the problem).

Comment: A toggle control would look pretty strange.